# Добавить действие в контекстное меню элемента инфоблока битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, метапрограммирование

Нужно добавить собственное действие, а лучше групповое действие для элементов инфоблока? сделал добавление в контекстное меню так:

```
AddEventHandler("main", "OnAdminListDisplay", "MyOnAdminListDisplay");
function MyOnAdminListDisplay(&$list)
{
    //add custom group action

    $list->arActions["create_dublicat"] = "Создать дубликат";
}
```

теперь как добавить обработчик этого события?

Answer (score 1):

Пример из [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onadminlistdisplay.php)

```
<?
AddEventHandler("main", "OnAdminListDisplay", "MyOnAdminListDisplay");
function MyOnAdminListDisplay(&$list)
{
    //add custom group action
    if($list->table_id == "tbl_posting")
        $list->arActions["status_draft"] = "Статус: Черновик";
}
//process custom action
AddEventHandler("main", "OnBeforeProlog", "MyOnBeforeProlog");
function MyOnBeforeProlog()
{
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && $_POST["action"] == "status_draft" && is_array($_POST["ID"]) && $GLOBALS["APPLICATION"]->GetCurPage() == "/bitrix/admin/posting_admin.php")
    {
        if($GLOBALS["APPLICATION"]->GetGroupRight("subscribe") == "W" && check_bitrix_sessid())
        {
            if(CModule::IncludeModule("subscribe"))
            {
                $cPosting = new CPosting;
                foreach($_POST["ID"] as $ID)
                    if(($ID = intval($ID)) > 0)
                        $cPosting->ChangeStatus($ID, "D");
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Да видел этот пример, прописал свой код но ничего не получилось

Comment: Может проблема была именно там? Отладочный вывод или трассировку организовывали?

Comment: пробовал вызвать просто создание пустого файла, чтобы проверить зашел в код или нет, но ничего не произошло

Comment: Т..е. функция аналогичная MyOnBeforeProlog вообще у вас не работает? Даже без всяких условий?